# Change Cursor to Cross in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, cursor

I want to change the mouse cursor to a cross in excel using VBA however

```
Application.Cursor =
```

doesn't have a cross option available.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198335.aspx

```
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
```

Comment: xldefault doesn't change the cursor to a cross. I think the solution might be something other than using application.cursor.

Comment: File>Options>Advanced>Editing group:
-> Ensure 'Enable fill handle and cell drag and drop' is checked.

Comment: It's checked. and when I hover over the fill handle of a cell a cross cursor appears. however I still can't change the cursor to a cross using VBA.

Comment: What do you have instead of the cross?

Comment: At the moment I have the default cursor, depending on what I hover over.

Comment: Yes that's the one I see when I hover over cells. However when I hover over graphs I see an arrow and when I hover over text boxes I see the IBeam. I can use Application.Cursor = xlIBeam to permanently change the cursor to the IBeam. But is there an option to show a cross? (not xldefault)

Comment: According to the object browser, the only members of the xlMousePointer class are xlDefault, xlBeam, xlNorthwestArrow and xlWait.

Comment: Exactly, that's what i've discovered and I'm wondering if there is another way to change the cursor to a cross.

Answer (score 0):

Excel offers only limited number of cursors with original installation package. However more cursors can be purchased from MS-Excel sight, probably.